# Program compiled with gfortran, how to recompile with ifort?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Okay, I have the source code for a large open-source program on a Linux HPC.  There are two distinct systems that make up the HPC, arc1 and arc2, which share a filesystem.  Essentially, I need two separately compiled versions of this program, as the two systems have different libraries and compiler versions etc.  However, I would like to be able to compile both of these versions from the same source code.

The problem I am having is that once I have compiled the code once with a particular compiler, it seems to become "locked" to that particular compiler.  When I try to subsequently re-compile with a different compiler, even on the same system, it gives me many errors of the form:

```
[file.o]:[line]: undefined reference to '_gfortran_****'
```

where `****` is a number of different built-in Fortran functions.  I have to admit I know very little about how compilers actually work, so I am at a loss to explain this.

So, my query boils down to two main questions:

1) Is there any quick fix for the "undefined reference" errors between gfortran versions?  The code was initially compiled on arc1 with gfortran 4.1.2 and I am trying to compile it on arc2 with gfortran 4.4.7.

2) If not, is there any way to "unlock" the code so that I can re-compile it on both systems with ifort instead (as both systems have the same version of ifort installed)?  At the moment when I try to compile it with ifort on either system it throws up thousands of the "undefined reference" errors.

Comment: Are you sure you compile every library you use in the code with gfortran too?

Comment: I don't think so, the program is mainly in Fortran but I think a few graphical bits and bobs are in C++. The install script is constrained to use synonymous versions of the Fortran and C++ compilers.

Comment: There is clearly some object file linked in that was compiled by gfortran. The linker usually prints the name of the file. I believe it is the `file.o`.

Comment: So I would need to manually re-generate the object files before attempting re-compilation? I had assumed the install script would do this automatically.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you need a good `make clean` or whatever you do to clean everything up between builds. And in this case, everything means anything at all compiled, generated, or written by one of the compilers in question.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks guys, I've just tested it and a `make clean` command seems to accomplish the "unlocking".  Just for my own piece of mind before I do this with the actual program, doing a `make clean` on the source code won't interfere with the operation of an already compiled version will it?

Comment: Not if you copied it somewhere else.

Comment: Great, should be problem solved then. Thankyou both for your time and patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of the comments. The linker clearly receives object file named `file.o` that was compiled by gfortran and doesn't know where to find the symbols from the gfortran run-time libraries. The build script didn't recompile this file with the new compiler.

The solution is to use the facility of the particular build system, e.g. `make clean`, to delete all files produced by the previous build.

I note there may be problem also with the `.mod` files that some build scripts tend to ignore.